# how to setup action to delete message for inbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on custom inbox system. When I go to delete message it flashes a message that message is deleted. However I can still view the message from my inbox and by typing in the URL. How do I setup an action so that the message actually permanently deletes or at least gets place inside of a delete folder (that I have no created yet)?

message model:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :subject, :body, :sender_id, :recepient_id, :read_at,:sender_deleted,:recepient_deleted
    validates_presence_of :subject, :message => "Please enter message title"

    belongs_to :sender,
    :class_name => 'User',
    :foreign_key => 'sender_id'
    belongs_to :recepient,
    :class_name => 'User',
    :foreign_key => 'recepient_id'

    # marks a message as deleted by either the sender or the recepient, which ever the user that was passed is.
    # When both sender and recepient marks it deleted, it is destroyed.
    def mark_message_deleted(id,user_id)
        self.sender_deleted = true if self.sender_id == user_id and self.id=id
        self.recepient_deleted = true if self.recepient_id == user_id and self.id=id
        self.sender_deleted && self.recepient_deleted ? self.destroy : save!
    end

    # Read message and if it is read by recepient then mark it is read
    def self.readingmessage(id, reader)
        message = find(id, :conditions => ["sender_id = ? OR recepient_id = ?", reader, reader])
        if message.read_at.nil? && (message.recepient.user_id==reader)
            message.read_at = Time.now
            message.save!
        end
        message
    end

    # Based on if a message has been read by it's recepient returns true or false.
    def read?
        self.read_at.nil? ? false : true
    end

    def self.received_by(user)
       where(:recepient_id => user.id)
     end

     def self.not_recepient_deleted
       where("recepient_deleted = ?", false)
     end

end
```

message controller:

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :set_user

  def index
    if params[:mailbox] == "sent"
      @messages = @user.sent_messages
    elsif params[:mailbox] == "inbox"
      @messages = @user.received_messages
    #elsif params[:mailbox] == "archieved"
     # @messages = @user.archived_messages
    end
  end

  def new
    @message = Message.new
    if params[:reply_to]
      @reply_to = User.find_by_user_id(params[:reply_to])
      unless @reply_to.nil?
        @message.recepient_id = @reply_to.user_id
      end
    end
  end

  def create
    @message = Message.new(params[:message])
    @message.sender_id = @user_id
    if @message.save
      flash[:notice] = "Message has been sent"
      redirect_to user_messages_path(current_user, :mailbox=>:inbox)
    else
      render :action => :new
    end
  end

  def show
    @message = Message.find(params[:id])
  end

  def delete_multiple
      if params[:delete]
        params[:delete].each { |id|
          @message = Message.find(id)
          @message.mark_message_deleted(@message.id,@user_id) unless @message.nil?
        }
        flash[:notice] = "Messages deleted"
      end
      redirect_to user_messages_path(@user, @messages)
  end

  private
    def set_user
      @user = current_user
    end
end
```

inbox view:

```
<h2>Your Inbox</h2>
<% if @messages.size == 0 %>
No messages in your Inbox
<% end %>
<% else %>
        <%= form_tag delete_multiple_user_messages_path, :method=>:post do %>
            <table  class="table table-bordered">
                    <tr>
                    <th>Delete?</th>
                    <th>Sent</th>
                    <th>Sender</th>
                    <th>Sent</th>
                </tr>
                    <% for message in @messages %>
                        <tr>
                            <td><%= check_box_tag "delete[]", message.id %></td>
                            <td>
                                <% if message.read? %>
                                  <%= link_to h(message.subject), user_message_path(@user, message) %>
                                <% else %>
                                  <%= link_to "#{h(message.subject)} (unread)", user_message_path(@user, message) %>
                                <% end %>
                            </td>

                            <td><%=h message.created_at.to_s(:long) %></td>
                        </tr>
            <% end %>
            </table>
        <%= submit_tag "Delete selected" %> |
        <% end %>
<%= link_to "Compose New Message", new_user_message_path(@user)%> | 
<%= link_to "View Sent Messages", user_messages_path(current_user, :mailbox => :sent)%>
```

Comment: Are the messages exactly deleting from the database or not? You said that you are getting the flash message. Can you past the controller code also?

Comment: In `delete_multiple` method, you are not deleting the messages from the database, simply updating the status. As they are still existing in the database, one can get their view page if we go to the particular url. Do you need to keep them without deleting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we go...

One way is to delete the messages permanently from the database, so that they wont be available further even if one can hit the specific url.

or if you want to do soft-delete the messages instead of permanently deleting from the database, in that case, you have to add one condition in the `show` method so that if a message is soft-deleted, then `index` page.

so your `show` method could be

```
def show
  @message = Message.where(:id => params[:id], :deleted => false).first
  redirect_to messages_path unless @message.present?
end
```

in the above query, i assumed that `deleted` is the field which can be used to tell weather one has deleted or not. And the above query will return a message if only that `deleted` is false.

**UPDATE:**

After checking your method `mark_message_deleted` in model, modify the method as below

```
def mark_message_deleted(id,user_id)
    self.sender_deleted = true if self.sender_id == user_id
    self.recepient_deleted = true if self.recepient_id == user_id
    (self.sender_deleted && self.recepient_deleted) ? self.destroy : self.save!
end
```

this one alone is sufficient.

Comment: Using the first method I get a: "Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'messages.deleted' in 'where clause': SELECT  `messages`.* FROM `messages`  WHERE `messages`.`id` = 39 AND `messages`.`deleted` = 0 LIMIT 1". Says statement is invalid for show. If using your update with making those slight changes to the model..it does not affect anything. The messages still load after being deleted.

Comment: I ran the delete feature in console and it is showing nil for most options. So something is set to stop it from deleting. The above code is correct, there is something else I am not aware of that is preventing:  DELETE FROM `messages` WHERE `messages`.`id` = 44
 => #<Message id: 44, sender_id: 16, recepient_id: 16, subject: "test", null: nil, container: nil, sender_deleted: nil, recepient_deleted: nil, read_at: nil, body: "testing delete feature", created_at: "2013-04-04 18:31:42", updated_at: "2013-04-04 18:31:42">